# How to change Minecraft key bindings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to change  key bindings in Minecraft for example <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, etc?

I had no luck googling. I really want to know if there is a way to do this because I play on mac and you need to keep going into settings to do it. I really would like to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can only rebind these system/debug keys:

- Highlight Players (spectators) - no default key
- Take Screenshot - default <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Toggle Cinematic Camera - no default key
- Toggle Fullscreen - default <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Toggle Perspective (3rd person view) - default <kbd>F5</kbd>

That is, you can't rebind the Toggle HUD (<kbd>F1</kbd>) and Toggle Debug Screen (<kbd>F3</kbd>) button.

If your PC runs on newer versions of Windows (*shudder*), the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys have different functions. In order to use them in Minecraft, you must "override" Windows' F-key functions, by pressing one of the following keys when you press your F-key:

- <kbd>fn</kbd>
- <kbd>WIN</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>shift</kbd> / <kbd>alt</kbd>

---

There is no mod I'm aware of that is capable of what you request; You can try to find one if you want. You can also use a keyboard/mouse macro.